# Is there a way to get all permission granted to an application

Tags: android, permissions, runtime

I am trying to request all permissions recently granted to an application by a user. That means all granted with installation and requested by runtime. I mean something like

```
String[] grantedPermissions = getAlreadyGrantedPermission(context)
```

or something else